# React - 'react-d3-graph' not rendering Chart component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-d3-graph

I've taken the example of 'react-d3-graph' at :

https://codesandbox.io/s/long-wood-7evr8?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js:138-417

I'm attempting to render the Graph component within the 'react-d3-graph' working with non hardcoded data by reading data from a file using fetch.

But when I read the data from a file via a fetch() and assign the data read from the file to  component I get these messages in the console and nothing is displayed.

**react-d3-graph :: Graph : you have not provided enough data for react-d3-graph to render something. You need to provide at least one node**

**react-d3-graph :: Graph :: you are passing invalid data to react-d3-graph. You must include a links array, even if empty, in the data object you're passing down to the  component.**

This message is displayed before the console output of the data read in from the file so it's a timing issue. I've tried reading around but can't find a way round this.

Can anyone please help. Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";

class GraphView extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        data : {}
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://10.10.1.185:4200/chartdata.txt")

        .then((r) => r.text())
        .then(text => {
            console.log("text=" + text);
            this.state.data = text
            console.log("this.state.data=" + this.state.data)
        })
}

render() {

    const myConfig = {
        nodeHighlightBehavior: true,
        node: {
            color: "lightgreen",
            size: 200,
            highlightStrokeColor: "blue",
        },
        link: {
            highlightColor: "lightblue",
        },
    };

    const onClickNode = function (nodeId) {
        window.alert(`Clicked node ${nodeId}`);
    };

    const onClickLink = function (source, target) {
        window.alert(`Clicked link between ${source} and ${target}`);
    };

    const onMouseOverNode = function (nodeId, node) {
        window.alert(`Alarms for ${nodeId}  Coords: (${node.x}, ${node.y})`);
    };
    
    const onRightClickNode = function (event, nodeId) {
        const clickedNode = { nodeId };
        window.alert(`onRightClickNode link  ${event} and ${nodeId}`);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            
            <Graph
                id="graph-id" 
                data={this.state.data}
                config={myConfig}
                onClickNode={onClickNode}
                onClickLink={onClickLink}
                onRightClickNode={onRightClickNode}                

            />;
        </div>
    );
}
}

export default GraphView
```

Comment: Looks like you are not getting data from `fetch("http://10.10.1.185:4200/chartdata.txt")`. What do you see when `console.log("text=" + text);`

Comment: text=[{
                nodes: [{ id: "Harry" }, { id: "Sally" }, { id: "Alice" }, { id: "Bob" },],
                links: [
                    { source: "Harry", target: "Sally" },
                    { source: "Harry", target: "Alice" },
                    { source: "Alice", target: "Bob" },
                ],
}]

Comment: Did you parse the data? `r.text()` makes it a string l suppose. If you didn't parse, parse the response with JSON.parse()

Comment: Right in the place you see the data `text=[{ nodes: [{ id: "Harry" }, { id: "Sally" }, ...]` set the state. Make sure it is not a stringified value. If it is, first parse it then store

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: I haven't parsed the data. When you say parse the return data do you mean myObject = JSON.parse(text)  and use myObject in Graph component?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are directly manipulating the state rather than using `setState`. In react you must never manipulate the state directly. So change

```
.then(text => {
     console.log("text=" + text);
     this.state.data = text
     console.log("this.state.data=" + this.state.data)
 })
```

to:

```
.then(text => {
     console.log("text=" + text);
     this.setState({data: text})
     console.log("this.state.data=" + this.state.data)
 })
```

Comment: I'm using 'data' in the Graph component so did you mean to say try
  this.setState({ data : text })

This errors with:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')